# How do I resize the toolbar and fonts in Proteus?

Tags: proteus

The workspace is just fine but all of the toolbar have really small icons and fonts are also really small.[image]

Comment: That's your display settings.

Comment: I cant find any display setings in the app to change the size. @Elementronics

Comment: the OS display settings

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type `winecfg`, then in tab *Graphics*, increase *Screen resolution* will fix it, good luck! [image: Wine configuration]